# How do I call GET from within a model spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an auditing model, and I'd like to test that a new record is added when a HTTP request is made.

I can't seem to call

```
get "/"
```

as I would in a controller spec. I get a no method error instead. What am I missing?

Cheers,
Graeme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and you should not write controller specs inside model specs. RSpec adds controller-related APIs only to controller specs so you will never be able to call #get #post #put and #delete inside a model spec.

You can read README in rspec-rails project to get an idea of what to test and where: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Hi Solnic. That seems reasonable, but how do I test the application_controller as it's not directly accessible. Is it? I could just pick a normal controller to test it, but that seems to be taking the test away from from where it's most relevant. Thanks.

Comment: application_controller is the base of all your controllers so if there's a shared behavior then you should write a shared spec for it and use it in all of your controller specs

Here's a nice article about shared specs: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/11/07/specifying-mixins-with-shared-example-groups-in-rspec-2/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do the name of the action...so for example

```
get :show
```

or

```
get :edit
```

or even

```
get :new
```

Comment: Nope, I still get a "no method" error for get. Plus, given that I'm in a model spec, not a controller, it wouldn't know which controller to apply the action to.

Comment: so I'm confused as to why you'd call controller actions from the model spec? You should be using mocks, stubs and fake input to represent that stuff. Specs should isolate the layers from one another, aside from integration tests that can span the layers. This is general practice, not Law, of course.  As for why the call isn't working, I'm not sure--never tried to do this from a model. I don't know if there's a difference, quite honestly

Comment: The audit is triggered with a before_filter method in the application controller, so I'm trying to check that a call to any URL will result in the creation of an audit record. It seemed like the logical way to test this, but I'm new to RSpec!

Comment: It took me a while to wrap my head around the rspec world...still I get confused. I would test controller behavior in the controller. I'll look for a good link on using rspec "the rails way"...

Comment: Ok, well, quite sadly the best sources I've seen are the Rspec documentation, and the Rspec Book:  http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book